# How to draw estimates based on variance covariance matrix?

Tags: r, regression, random-generation, covariance-matrix

Suppose I fitted a logistic model and get the estimates as well as their `vcov` matrix. I would realize this: draw length($\beta_s$) independent $\mathcal N(0,1)$ values to create a random vector $z$, then $\beta^*$=$\hat{\beta}+Az$ where $A$ is the upper triangular matrix of the Cholesky decomposition matrix ($\hat{V}=A'A$). How can I draw the $\beta^*$ using the `vcov` matrix? Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(y=rbinom(100,1,0.5),
                 x1=rnorm(100,10,2),
                 x2=rbinom(100,20,0.6))

fit <- glm(y~x1+x2, data=df, family="binomial")
```

$\hat{\beta}$:

```
coef(summary(fit))
            Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.1482    1.57451  0.09413   0.9250
x1           -0.1710    0.10962 -1.55984   0.1188
x2            0.1181    0.09047  1.30567   0.1917
```

vcov matrix:

```
vcov(fit)
(Intercept)      2.4791 -0.1225802 -0.1020612
x1              -0.1226  0.0120164  0.0003505
x2              -0.1021  0.0003505  0.0081844
```

Would somebody know how to draw new $\beta^*$ using the `coef` and `vcov`?

Comment: You know what you want to do and how to do it, so I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: I am in trouble on how to get $\beta^*$ based on $\hat{\beta}$ and `vcov`.

Comment: you already told us how to do that: $\hat{\beta} + \mathbf{A}z$, so what is the problem?

Comment: How to implement the formula to the example?

Comment: What did you try before posting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = 3 # number of parameters
newbeta <- coef(fit) + chol(vcov(fit))%*%rnorm(p)
newbeta
                   [,1]
(Intercept)  3.52525853
x1          -0.05357471
x2           0.11368681
```

Explanation:

- `p` is the number of parameters which is the number of predictors in the fit model plus 1 (intercept).
- `coef(fit)` retrieves the fitted estimates which is a $1 \times p $ matrix.
- `vcov(fit)` retrieves the variance-covariance matrix which is a $p \times p$ matrix.
- `chol(vcov(fit))` computes the Cholesky Decomposition matrix which is also a $p \times p$ matrix. for more information about the Cholesky Decomposition click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).
- `rnorm(p)` is the random $z$ values matrix ($3 \times 1$) from $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distribution with `p` length.

Comment: For the question and the answer to be on topic here, they need to be expressed in a way that is understandable to non-`R` users.  Mathematical notation and/or English descriptions would be good choices.